# Не обновляются данные в HTML при биндинге из AngularJS контроллера

Tags: angularjs

Существует базовый контроллер со свойством, значение которого обновляется при возникновении события.

```
export class ListController {

    protected selectedRowCount: any;

    constructor() {
       //some initial code 
    }

    protected onInit() {
        var self = this;
        this.gridOptions.api.eventService.addEventListener("selectionChanged", function () {
            if (self !== undefined) {
                self.selectedRowCount = self.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes().length;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

От этого контроллера наследуются другие контроллеры, которые привязываются к представлению.

```
<span>{{сtrl.selectedRowCount}}</span>
```

Отображаемое значение не изменяется при обновлении значения переменной.

Comment: что за eventservice и addEventListener?

Comment: Это не `AngularJS`, это `Angular`;)

Comment: Попробуйте строку `var self = this` переместить на "уровень" класса, а не метода

Comment: @notaProgrammer это `angularjs` с реализацией на `typescript`, к тому же зачем перемещать `var self = this` и зачем вообще нужно объявление этой переменной?